# Force EMF to not override implementation

Tags: java, graph, javafx, emf, eclipse-gef

I want to create a graphical representation for several chained event-listener-pairs based on a JavaFX library (https://github.com/tesis-dynaware/graph-editor). Because EMF is used, further details of the library do not matter. So it could be imagined as a replacement of GEF.

Following diagram shows a minimal example of the data model (for a easier understanding imagine `Source` rendered next to `Sink`)

[image: Class diagram]

Source and sink are the nodes. Multiple sinks can be connected to one source.

I tried using EMF "annotations" to create the model

```
/**
 * Concrete message listener.
 * 
 * @model
 */
public class Sink implements MessageListener
{
    @Override
    public void onMessage( MessageEvent e )
    {
        System.out.println( e.getMessage() );
    }
}
```

but generating the model overwrites my implementation and for example the `implements MessageListener` is replaced by `implements InternalSink`.
How can I force EMF to not touch my implementation and creating the meta information in a separate file?

Answer (score 1):

Annotate generated code (methods, fields, classes) with

```
@generated NOT
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but maybe I need to point out a little bit more, that I rather want reverse engineer my existing code with EMF. I found an article in the Eclipse Community Forums: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=134122/, but there is not a satisfying answer in it.